# TabItem text background is not setting properly: android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-tablayout

I was designing a tab layout with two tabitem. I wanted to make tabitem text background yellow and blue. But a white background is coming. Moreover, tabindicator is not showing due to the white background of the text.

[image: tab text background looks like this]

```
       <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/bsu_tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/text1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/buttonback2"
            app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/signup_tab_background">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="#E0E"
                android:text="Signup">

            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem>
            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="Login">

            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem>
        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/bsu_viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/bsu_tabLayout"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:background="@color/background"/>
```

how should I remove this white part?

Comment: Check if it depends by app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch"

Comment: No, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

please remove `tabBackground` and check.

```
app:tabBackground="@drawable/signup_tab_background"
```